# TableAdapter.Update not working after deleting a row using TableBindingNavigator

Tags: c#, tableadapter, bindingnavigator

I would really appreciate your help as I have been struggling with this for two days now.

When I first build the solution, I can add new records, delete/edit any data value and everything works fine. Then, I can save the data using the save button in the TableBindingNavigator and up to this point everything still work fine.

However, after the first save, I cannot save again after deleting or editing any existing data value from the table although the table gird view will update as I am editing/deleting. I am getting the following errors: 
If I click save,I get an error saying "Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows."
If I edit any data, I get an error saying "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Hatch_Optimizer.Properties;

namespace Hatch_Optimizer
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void tblVarBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.tblVarBindingSource.EndEdit();
        tblVarTableAdapter.Update(this.dsHatchOpt);
        //this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dsHatchOpt);
    }

    private void tblResBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.tblVarBindingSource.EndEdit();
        tblResTableAdapter.Update(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
       this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dsHatchOpt);
    }



    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.tblResTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
        this.tblResTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
        this.tblResTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
        this.tblResTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
        this.tblResTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblRes);
        this.tblVarTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsHatchOpt.tblVar);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You go to your table adapter properties, there you find the commands like InsertCommand,UpdateCommand,DeleteCommand,SelectCommand.....
in these,the commandtext property must be defined like an example below
Its not a proper one, doesn't check anything just delete the selected row from a datatabla based on a row position of a specific column

DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE        (yourColumname = ?)

i hope will help